# Binding jquery-ui events to backbone events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a backbone view set up like so:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click' : 'clickOnitHandler',
        'stop' : 'dropHandler'
    },

// Rest of class
```

What I would like to do here is hook a jquery-ui event for the draggable control.

This would usually be done like so (with jquery):

```
 $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      start: function() {
         // stuff
      },
 });
```

So this would go in the render() method of the backbone view, which doesn't seem quite right. I would prefer it to be declared in the events array for the view.

But not sure how to make it accessible here.

Comment: Have you tried putting a [`dragstart`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) in `events`?

Comment: yes that worked, but I can't accept this is an answer.

Comment: You can answer your own questions (and accept those answers after, AFAIK, a day). My comment was a guess so I didn't feel comfortable with anything more than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this. Simply like this.

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click' : 'clickOnitHandler',
        'dragstop' : 'dropHandler',
    },
```